# line breaks from textarea to database and then to display

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am using a ready script, which includes account registration and a few functions. Users can edit a text area on their profile which is saved on a database, is a description for something.

Editing the template of my script/web i would like to make it, when a user writes for example:

```
One
Two
Three
```

to be displayed like this also cause right now its like

```
One Two Three
```

I'made a re-search on the file's and found out the followings:

```
$description_prepare = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), ' ', $FORM['description']);
$TMPL['description'] = $DB->escape($description_prepare, 1);
$TMPL['description'] = $this->bad_words($TMPL['description']);
$TMPL['description'] = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 .,\-]/', '', $TMPL['description']);
```

as you can see the script is replacing the line breaks with a space ' '.
i removed this part completely and made it like

```
$TMPL['description'] = $DB->escape($FORM['description'], 1);
$TMPL['description'] = $this->bad_words($TMPL['description']);
$TMPL['description'] = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 .,\-]/', '', $TMPL['description']);
```

but now when i am editing the description for example from

```
One Two Three
```

to

```
One
Two Three
```

i am getting back

```
Onern Two Three
```

How can i solve this?

---

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Try using `htmlentities()` before writing to the DB and then  `html_entity_decode()` when displaying the information back ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php      http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: If this approach works then you may not need to include all the additional code that you currently have.

Comment: but i think this way, would give the opportunity to user's to modify also the color's and in general the html structure which is something i don't want, description should be displayed as plain text, also what if someone add on his description </div> or </html> that would destroy the whole design, especially if wanna use this description on the main index would be a huge disaster.

Comment: I think that is a valid concern. You can probably search SO for a potential solution or post another question here if you can't find a solution. You could also do something like having only a  restricted list of "allowed" HTML tags or something like that.

Comment: i think with the current code thats what preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 .,\-]/', '' and escape function does, replacing not valid/good like <> / chars. i am beginner with php so i am not sure

Comment: I think `htmlentities()` would take care of many of those cases too.